# How to replicate Solr index per filter query?

Tags: solr

I need to replicate or copy a subset of a Solr index. How might I define a filter query and replicate or copy only those documents matched by the filter query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the use of the [SolrEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#SolrEntityProcessor) that is part of the overall Solr [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) process to extract the desired subset. The SolrEntityProcessor will allow you to specify a query to execute for selecting documents and will allow you to filter as needed. You will need to use Solr 3.6 or higher to leverage the use of SolrEntityProcessor.